# Context Free Grammar for Strings with Length Divisible by 3

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to create a context free grammar that will generate strings over {a,b} whose length is *not* divisible by 3. I don't really know where to begin with this. If somebody could provide a similar example or a starting point that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a grammar of binary number divisible by 5 with 1 as MSB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219439/find-a-grammar-of-binary-number-divisible-by-5-with-1-as-msb)

Comment: Can you make a grammar that creates only strings that *are* divisble by three? Then, how can you modify the grammar (wrapping another rule around it) so that the generated strings are *not* divisible by three?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's do a bit of brainstorming to start with.

- Is every regular grammar context-free as well? Yes.
- Do we know any regular grammar which makes strings **divisible** by 3? Well that's not too hard, we do.
- Next thing there is is conversion algorithm from regular grammar to finite automaton.
- Converting automaton to a one which accepts complement is quite easy (just make the transition function total and switch the accepting and nonaccepting states).
- Next step is to convert finite automaton back to regular grammar (also known algorithm).
- Now we have regular grammar and from the first line we know, that each reg. grammar is CFG as well.

For sure there is more straightforward solution (let's say to generate sentential forms which will be divisible by 3, but then adding 1 or 2 chars to them), but this gives you a bit of an insight into how all these things are connected.

Hope this at answers your question at least a bit. Feel free to ask for more details.

EDIT:
I also added the regular grammar which generates such language (initial nonterminal is 0):

```
0 -> a1 | b1 | a | b
1 -> a2 | b2 | a | b
2 -> a0 | b0
```

Basicaly what the grammar does is trying to get word length divisible by 3, but whenever it should add third char, it disallows you to terminate generating.